# Scraping a specific tweet's data from Twitter in R

Tags: r, twitter

R data analysts,
I tried to scrape all retweeters' user names (i.e. screen_names) from a specific tweet, but 'get_retweeters' function in 'rtweet' package does not seem to be able to do so. How can I scape all the screen_names (i.e. twitter accounts) of the people who retweeted the following tweet:
https://twitter.com/POTUS/status/1366863876206264327?s=20

Example:

```
status_id = '1366863876206264327'
test_tweet=rtweet::get_retweeters(status_id, n = 100, parse = TRUE, token = NULL)
test_tweet # this shows only "user_id"s, but it does not show the "screen_name".
```

I need the "screen_name"s of whoever retweeted this tweet. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm able to run the get_retweeters function without any problems. Your issue may be that the token parameter is NULL in your example. You need to apply for API credentials through the Twitter Developer site (takes a few weeks to get these unfortunately!).

Comment: Thank you. get_retweeters function allows to only scrape 98 screen_names, I need like 20k screen_names. Is there anyway? other websites? Thanks again.

Comment: I think the Twitter API is the only reliable source for this information. I'd go ahead and create a developer account if you haven't already. Also, if you want more retweets than can be provided through the rtweet package you may need to look at the httr package and the Twitter API documentation. Getting thousands of retweeter user names is possible with the GET function with the right parameters. Not an easy task if you're new to this though!

Comment: Thank you very much, @bbspring. I appreciate your help.